# Suggested actions wait for user to choose first

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) in the docs. I am using Botframework v4.

But it is not waiting for the user to choose first before going to the next step.
How do you implement this? Do you put it in a prompt? How to get the value of the selected suggested action in the next prompt?

And when to use suggested actions and when to use choice prompt?

```
AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
{
    var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("What can i do for you?");
    reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
    {
        Actions = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction() { Title = "Learn more!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Learn more!" },
            new CardAction() { Title = "Opportunities!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Opportunities!" },
            new CardAction() { Title = "Define my goals!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Define my goals!" },
            new CardAction() { Title = "Finko.ph", Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl, Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q" },
        },
    };
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
});

//how to wait for user choice before moving to the next step.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Suggested Actions vs Choice Prompts

Suggested Actions, by design, disappear as soon as any other message is sent ([see opening paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)). They're meant to be versatile and used for when you prompt a user for input, but also allow the user to type anything outside of the suggested actions you present them. For example, you might ask a user their favorite color and suggest `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, but allow the user to type any color they want. [This bot sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/08.suggested-actions/SuggestedActionsBot.cs) does something similar. Suggested Actions, if sent in a message, *will not* wait for user input. However, if you use them in a text prompt, they will. More on that below.

Choice Prompts restrict users to either clicking on the buttons you present them or typing in exactly what's on the buttons (or [`Synonyms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choices.choice.synonyms?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Choices_Choice_Synonyms)). If they enter anything else, they are re-prompted to enter one of the choices. Choice prompts, since they are prompts, automatically wait for user input.

In short:

- Suggested actions can collect any user input, and can be sent in a message or as part of a text prompt.
- Choice prompts restrict a user's input and always waits for that input.

## Sending Suggested Actions in a Text Prompt

I've modified your code so that you can send your suggested actions as part of a text prompt. This will wait for user input before continuing to the next waterfall step. However, *any* text that the user enters will be considered valid. If you want to restrict the user to only a few choices, use a choice prompt (further below)

Suggested Actions Text Prompt:

```
var opts = new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = new Activity
    {
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Text = "What can i do for you?",
        SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Learn more!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Learn more!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Opportunities!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Opportunities!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Define my goals!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Define my goals!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Finko.ph", Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl, Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q" },
            },
        },
    }
};

// Display a Text Prompt with suggested actions and wait for input
return await stepContext.PromptAsync("textPrompt", opts);
```

#### Getting the Value of a Suggested Action Prompt

Since the Suggested Action is used in a Text Prompt, the value shows up in `stepContext.Result`

[image]

## Restricting User Choices Using a Choice Prompt

I've adapted your code to use a Choice Prompt, which will wait for user input. **Note that choice prompts don't allow for `OpenUrl`; when the user clicks an option with the `OpenUrl` action, it will clear the choices and not continue, even if you use [`DisplayText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.cardaction?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable).** Instead, in the next waterfall step, you could present the URL to the user if they click the "Finko.ph" option (after adding it with `opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Finko.ph" });`).

```
// In constructor
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("choicePrompt"));

...

// In waterfall step
var opts = new PromptOptions()
{
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What can i do for you?"),
    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, please choose an option from the list."),
    Choices = new List<Choice>(),
};

opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Learn more!" });
opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Opportunities!" });
opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Define my goals!" });

// Display a Choice Prompt and wait for input
return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt", opts);
```

#### Getting the Value from a Choice Prompt

The value for a Choice Prompt shows up in `stepContext.Result.Value`

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir i understand it better now.

Comment: Additional question sir. Can a suggested action of type openUrl also do like the 'imBack' suggested action? Like it will open the url but it will also send a text like the 'imBack' action type.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only set one `ActionType` at a time, so no.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building the `Activity` yourself and sending it using `SendActivityAsync`, you would want to use the prompting capabilities of the Dialog APIs. In this case you want to use a `ChoicePrompt` which will help ensure that one of the choices is selected before allowing the conversation to proceed.

First, add a choice prompt to your `DialogSet`:

```cs
// Add the prompt with the suggested action list style
myDialogSet.Add(new ChoicePrompt("myChoicePrompt") { Style = ListStyle.None });
```

Now, the `ListStyle.None` is important here for your scenario because you have an extra requirement in your design that, along with the choices, you're also presenting a link that can be opened. By using `None` you're telling the `ChoicePrompt` that you're going to handle building the `Activity` yourself and that it shouldn't perform any of that work for you.

Next, update your waterfall step to utilize this prompt:

```cs
AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
        "myChoicePrompt",
        new PromptOptions 
        {
            Prompt = BuildCardChoicePromptActivity(),
            Choices = new List<Choice>
            {
                new Choice("Learn more!"),
                new Choice("Opportunities!"),
                new Choice("Define my goals!"),
            }
         },
         cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
});

// Factored this out into its own method for clarity (NOTE: you don't need to use CreateReply)
private Activity BuildCardChoicePromptActivity()
{
    return new Activity
    {
        Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
        Text = "What can I do for you?",
        SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Learn more!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Learn more!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Opportunities!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Opportunities!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Define my goals!", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Define my goals!" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Finko.ph", Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl, Value = "https://m-moreno.wixsite.com/finkoph?fbclid=IwAR1NVtlyKfzZ0mYFIWva8L-d8TUv4KFpt_m1i1ij3raT-pbWr2c3-kqzB2Q" },
            },
        },
    };
}
```

In closing, your scenario is a little more advanced because of the `OpenUrl` action you want to include along side of your actual choices, but the key takeaway should be using the `ChoicePrompt` to present the actions and block the conversation until one of the specificed `Choices` is sent back.

Comment: The issue with this is that if the user selects "Finko.ph", it will clear the options and not continue with the waterfall, even if you set `DisplayText` on the `CardAction`. Just something to watch out for. `OpenUrl` doesn't work well with `ChoicePrompt`

Comment: That's a good point @mdrichardson, that's probably not the UX you'd want. You may need a more complex UI using cards or something.

Comment: Thank you sir drew for the additional option!

Comment: Additional question sir. Can a suggested action of type openUrl also do like the 'imBack' suggested action? Like it will open the url but it will also send a text like the 'imBack' action type.

Answer (score 0):

On bot framework v3, you should add Context.Wait() to make the bot wait for a user input before proceeding. You also need to check if there's succeeding Post or Send activity after your suggestedAction code.

And when to use suggested actions and when to use choice prompt?

- Use Suggested actions if you're bot can receive inputs may or may not included in your suggestions.
- Use Choice prompt if your bot is expecting an input that is and should be included in the choices you provided. Common use is "yes" or "no"

Comment: Yes i seen in the docs in Botframework v3 but how to do it in v4?

Comment: try this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334280/bot-framework-v4-dialog-wait-for-user-input-without-prompting

Comment: I already tried that method but the suggested actions dissapears when the empty prompt appears.